# I want to control the legends in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, legend

Ask for help, how to make legend in matlab not display text, only display color?

As shown in the figure, i want to remove the text between each dashline but remain the legends, moreover, the legend with the box also needs to be preserved.
[image]

And I want the above figure to become like this.
[image]

```
%This is my code
%%
t = 0:0.01:1;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = cos(t);
y3 = sin(t)+cos(t);
h = plot(t,y1,t,y2,t,y3);
legend('y1','y2','y3')
ah=axes('position',get(gca,'position'),'visible','off');
h1 = legend(ah,h([1 3]),'y1','y3');
h1.ItemTokenSize = [10,80];
set(h1,'FontSize',10,'position',[0.6,0.2,0.01,0.01],'units','normalized');
set(h1,'box','off')
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what the point of a legend would be without the text - please [edit] your question to include the code for a [mcve] of a demo plot, and an illustration of your desired before/after on how the legend should work

Comment: You can make the legends be an empty character, or a space.

Comment: If you don’t show how the plot was made, we can’t show you how to change your code to get rid of the text. But don’t dump all of your code here, create a [mre] that is enough for us to understand how you build your figure, and for you to understand how to update your own code.

Comment: First, thank you all for providing suggestions, but i am new here, I do not know how to reply to each one individually. The corresponding code and figure have been presented in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why I can't see the figure I uploaded.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question, don’t post additions to it as an answer. The answer box is only to answer the question at the top of the page. Being new and not knowing your way around is fine, but you could, for example, take the [tour] that was offered you.

Comment: in the function `legends`, do you understand what the line `h1 = legend(ah,h([1 3 4 10]),'t1','t3','t4','t10');` does? @AnderBiguri already told you how to modify this line to remove the text.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so late due to the time difference. In the function legends, i try to change the text in the "h1", i.e., change the 't1','t3','t4','t10', but it does not work.

Comment: The approach provieded by @AnderBiguri is effective for the legend without text. But i would like to achieve that the legend on the right have texts, but the others have not.

Comment: @ZhihangYu are you sure? there is still no [mcve] here, so we can't honestly help, but can't you simply empty strigns the ones you don't want to have a text and give a string to the ones you want? I can clearly see 2 calls to the function `legend` in your code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I am sorry. I have updated the code as an example. I just want to remove the text but remain color of the legend which is under the figure.

Comment: @AnderBiguri   As the time is late at night in China, i am afraid of  that i can not reply to you in time.  I hope that  the legend above the picture needs to be preserved and the legend below the image needs to remove the corresponding text but retain the color. I will greatly appreciate it for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit hacky, but basically what you want to do is make 2 plots, and hide one of them, having each of the plots a different legend.

```
t = 0:0.01:1;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = cos(t);
y3 = sin(t)+cos(t);

% plot twice
h = plot(t,y1,t,y2,t,y3);

hold on
% reset colors
set(gca,'ColorOrderIndex',1)
h2 = plot(t,y1,t,y2,t,y3);


% make first legend
legend(h,'y1','y2','y3')

% hide the latest axes
ah=axes('position',get(gca,'position'),'visible','off');
% add new legend in hidden second axis/plot
l1 = legend(ah,h2([1 3]),' ',' ');
% these next lines are not part of the solution, just your demo
l1.ItemTokenSize = [10,80];
set(l1,'FontSize',10,'position',[0.6,0.2,0.01,0.01],'units','normalized');
set(l1,'box','off')
```

[image]